# VS code says my branch has no remote branch when I try to push my commit, the branch appears on origin in the list of branches on VS Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I created a branch locally, made a few commits and pushed them to the remote (origin) using Git bash.
I'm now trying to use VS code instead of Git bash to manage git.

1. I opened my repo in VS code and I can see my branch (called DAIBIGW-5043), as well as branches on origin:
   [image]
2. I made some changes in my codes, committed them using VS Code:
   [image]
3. I then tried to push the changes via VS Code...
   [image]
4. ... and I get the following error message:
   [image]

Result of `git branch -vv`:

```
* DAIBIGW-5043 f42505c Fix Python code (mistalke in last commit only) and add the Summary sheet in the Excel export
* create_folders_structure e92d299 adding a folder structure and a sample code
* develop afa3652 [origin/develop] Merge pull request #57 from woolworthslimited/DAIBIGW-4904-pet-exco-slides
* main 5c4a544 [origin/main] Merge pull request #15 from woolworthslimited/ds_sprint_02
* mm_sprint26 a2f4b8a Merge pull request #3 from woolworthslimited/mm_sprint26
```

Note that I could successfully push the commits to the remote branch with Git bash

=> I'm super confused: Why does VS code says the branch has no remote when I push:
-- While it does shoes the remote branch on origin and even labels it as "remote branch" in the list
-- And while the branch does exist and I can push with Git bash?

Is there something I should configure in VS Code?

Comment: Perhaps there is a branch with the same name as the local branch but they are not linked to each other as upstream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `git branch -vv` shows

`* DAIBIGW-5043 f42505c Fix Python code (mistake in last commit only) and add the Summary sheet in the Excel export`

When a branch is tracking an upstream branch, then you'll see

`<branch ref> <commit hash> [<upstream branch ref>] <commit message>`

Your local branch isn't tracking the remote branch as its upstream branch.

You need to do:

`git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/DAIBIGW-5043 DAIBIGW-5043`

Comment: Thanks, Why does this happen in VS code only?

Comment: @MichaëlMénaché I don't know why pushing works through git-bash but not VS Code. You should provide more info about your repo config if you want an explanation for that. See also the docs for how `refspec` gets chosen if one isn't specified: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help! Things are working now, I'll deepen  my understanding later!